# Setting a string to null in C

Tags: c

Is setting a string to '\0' the same thing as setting a string to NULL in other languages?
Or... does setting a string to '\0' mean that the string is simply just empty?

```
char* str = '\0'
```

I have different functions to use for null strings and empty strings, so I don't want to accidentally call one of my empty string functions on a null string.

Comment: It's good practice to attach the `*` character to the variable name instead of the type name in order to avoid confusion. Consider `char* p1, p2;`. This defines a pointer-to-char p1 and a char p2, but it reads as if both p1 and p2 were of type pointer-to-char.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your line `char *str = '\0';` actually *DOES* set str to (the equivalent of) NULL. This is because `'\0'` in C is an integer with value 0, which is a valid null pointer constant. It's extremely obfuscated though :-)

Making `str` (a pointer to) an empty string is done with `str = "";` (or with `str = "\0";`, which will make str point to an array of *two* zero bytes).

Note: do not confuse your declaration with the statement in line 3 here

```
char *str;
/* ... allocate storage for str here ... */
*str = '\0'; /* Same as *str = 0; */
```

which does something entirely different: it sets the first character of the string that `str` points to to a zero byte, effectively making `str` point to the empty string.

Terminology nitpick: strings can't be set to NULL; a C string is an array of characters that has a NUL character somewhere. Without a NUL character, it's just an array of characters and must not be passed to functions expecting (pointers to) strings.
Pointers, however, are the only objects in C that can be NULL.
And don't confuse the NULL macro with the NUL character :-)

Comment: @Matteo are you sure that's only if it's in DOUBLE quotes, and that SINGLE quotes make it a char?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make a distinction between a declaration `char *str = '\0';` and the statement `*str = '\0';`. They do very different things.

Comment: @glowcoder: sorry, brainfart. I read `*str='\0'` instead of `char * str='\0'`. You got my +1 :)

Comment: @Matteo: no biggie; it was easy to confuse single and double quotes and I had to use my eagle eyes as well :-) Thanks for the vote, I appreciate it.

Comment: His line `char* str = '\0'` *actually* results in a compile time error: missing semicolon. Just nit-picking...  =)

Comment: `Without a NUL character, it's just an array of characters and must not be passed to functions expecting (pointers to) strings` Is this the reason why we need to initialize the string with the character `\0`, Does it work if I declare a `char *s;` and then pass it to a function for example `strcpy(s,src)` with src being "hello"

Comment: @Bionix No, that doesn't work, because `s` is not initialized. It points to no memory. You would need something like `s = malloc(42); strcpy (s, src);`.

Answer (score 1):

No, in this case you're pointing to a real (non-null) string with a length of 0. You can simply do the following to set it to actual null:

```
char* str = NULL;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. If it said `"\0"`, then it would.

Comment: Ahhh. Stupid single quotes. Good call!

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: According to the accepted answer, that would be "an array of *two* zero bytes."

Comment: @rvighne Uh so? Also that's still a string of length zero, because dumb C strings are NUL-terminated.